# Multiple animations jQuery - adding padding and displaying another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I guys,

So I have a sidebar that I want to slide in and out when a user clicks a button. When that sidebar slides out, I want the body of the page to add a padding so that the sidebar doesn't hide the page content. I have it working, it's just the animation is very jumpy. Any suggestions. Here is what I have.

```
var userQueueVis = false
$(document).on('click', '#user-queue-button', function() {
  if (userQueueVis == false) {
    $('.user-queue').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $(".main").animate({ 'padding-right' : '200px' }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#user-queue-button").addClass("active-button");
    userQueueVis = true;
  } else {
    $('.user-queue').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $(".main").animate({ 'padding-right' : '0px' }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#user-queue-button").removeClass("active-button");
    userQueueVis = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: You should use jQuery just to toggle the class, all the animation should be done via css.

Comment: Oh interesting. Good point. Ill try this out

Answer (score 0):

My snippet is not complete according to your needs but it gives you hit points what to do next, it toggle (show and hide) the sidebar (background red) along with adding padding to the specified parent div (#main). Hope this help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $("#sidebar").toggle("slide",function(){
      $("#main").toggleClass("padding_10px");
    });  
  });
});
```

```css
#main{border:1px solid blue;}
#sidebar{
 height:100vh;
 width:250px;
 background-color:red;
}
.padding_10px{padding:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <button>Click me!</button>
  <div id="sidebar">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Code Demon, will try and alter my code! Will let you know what happens